# What is chopping down my sunflowers?

Tags: pests, sunflowers

I had a small pot with three sunflowers in it (firecracker). They went down one by one, each with the same thing. See the image below, it looks like a tiny beaver chewed on the stem, just above the soil level.

Eventually the flower gets weak at that point and falls over.

Other than that the flower looks healthy and I don't notice any persistent pests. I see ants crawling around, but not a ton, and I don't think it's the ants doing this.

Any idea what would cause this and how I can address it organically?

[image]

Comment: are there wasps about? they will do this  and use the material they've chewed to create  their nests...

Comment: It's possible. I've seen a wasp or two around the yard.